# Jquery selector with 2 conditions

Tags: jquery, css-selectors

I am trying to initiate a function when a click event happens on a link within a list. This is for a menu.

Right now, I have this and it works:

```
$(".left-navigation-holder li a:has(~ul)").click(toggleMenu);
```

Basically, the click event initiate toggleMenu if the link clicked has a list (ul) down the tree. Now, I would also have this to happen only if that link href attribute is equal to nothing. I am trying this but doesnt work:

```
$(".left-navigation-holder li a.attr(href=''):has(~ul)").click(toggleMenu);
```

Any help would be much appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Why don't you put the logic in the handler? You can access what was clicked on in the toggleMenu function with $(this). Then do your checks in toggleMenu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
$(".left-navigation-holder li ul").closest("li").find("a[href='']").click(toggleMenu)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$(".left-navigation-holder ul").parent("li a[href='']").click(toggleMenu)
```

You can't embed the attr method inside the selector string.

Comment: sorry it does not, the first solution above does.

I thought I saw this a few minutes ago:
$(".left-navigation-holder li a[href='']:has(~ul)").click(toggleMenu);
And that worked well

Comment: I had assumed from your original question that you had nested the <ul> inside the <a>.  It didn't make sense to me why you would do that, but that is what is implied.  This script will work for that assumption, but, if the <ul> is a sibling to the <a> (which makes more sense), Reigel's script above will work.